# how to remove password from home page on fatfree framwork or selfoss application

Tags: password-protection, fat-free-framework

On my website there is a password applied on home page, Url of website is http://tru-breakthru.com/. Please tell me how can and from where I can remove it. Website is made with fatfree framework and with selfoss application. I don't know It is due to framework or due to selfoss application. I have gone through all files but I couldn't find the username password and also couldn't find the way to remove it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't find the username or the password it might be something like admin or something else along those lines and just try to find the primary page on your website and that should have every thing with the login

If you could share the files I could help you out more

Comment: Yes please, Is there any way to upload index.php file here ? or I should put all code here ? Because code is big.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/t/s!ApIEfp5YdNowhGZqCVXyBWnVmIPc
This is link of my index.php full file

Comment: on line 55 and 56 go into those html files and look for something that says password="" -or- password="(php file name)"